# How to delete a Private key associated with a certificate in LocalMachine store using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, scripting, certificate, private-key, certificate-store

I want to delete private key which is associated to a certificate in LocalMachine\Root using Powershell scripts. I need to first find this certificate from the store by using its friendly name since we don't have the thumbprint.

I used `Remove-Item -DeleteKey`, but it deletes only the certificate from the LocalMachine\Root but the private key is still present in the Personal folder.

I could not find any straight forward answers after searching many forums. Any help is appreciated.

Powershell version - 5.1, OS - Windows 10

I tried the below code and it deletes only the certificate from Root and not the Private key.

```
$certFriendlyName = 'MyTestCertificate'
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
$cert = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -match $certFriendlyName}
$cert
$cert | Remove-Item -DeleteKey
```

If i don't Set-Location, "-DeleteKey" switch is not working and throwing an error

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DeleteKey'
```

Comment: "but the private key is still present in the Personal folder."  If you have a copy in Root and a copy in My/Personal, it's quite likely that the copy in Root doesn't know it has a private key available ($cert.HasPrivateKey is probably false).

Comment: And even if `$cert.HasPrivateKey` is false, the "I have a private key" icon and `$cert.HasPrivateKey` are both keyed off of "is there metadata that tells me where my private key is" (CERT_PROP_KEY_PROV_ID), not "and does it exist".  So the private key might be deleted, and trying to use it will fail from the copy in My/Personal.